# Lotus Notes formula language : Compose document with default values

Tags: lotus-domino

What I need is ,
I have a button in a form where
with formula language (not in lotus script)
I compose a new form using @Command([Compose]; ""; "myForm");
but I need to pass some field value  from  current form .
The @SetField works for current form.
Is there any option ;
If I run Agent @command is possible to run with  parameter in order to send current document ID and to create myForm , having values from current form ?

Thanks to advice me !

Answer (score 4):

If document A with current form is selected, when you create document B with another form, then you simply enable the FORM- Property "Formulas Inherit Values from selected document" on the second tab of the properties.

In the field- formulas of form B just enter the name of the Field in Form A as Formula. e.G.: If the field in Form A is named "AEmail" then enter AEmail in the Value of field "BEmail" of Form B.

Beware: this "inheritance" is only done ONCE when the document is created, there will be no relation between the two documents to update BEmail, if AEmail changes. To update the values dependantly you would need to construct something like @GetDocField( unidOfDocA; "AEmail" ) but that would need some more knowledge of the formula language.